# sort and pick by column while keeping the original index in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Say that I have three columns with name 'a', 'b' and 'c'. All the values in the three columns have different range and are random.

What I want to do is:

1. Keep the row index.
2. Pick column 'a'. Sort the values from the smallest to the biggest in column 'a'.
3. Slice the sorted column 'a' into certain sections. For example, from smallest value to 1/3 of the biggest value, 1/3 to 2/3 and 2/3 to the biggest. That's three sections in total.
4. Randomly pick three rows in each section.
5. Exclude the original index of the rows that are picked so I won't pick the same rows again.
6. Repeat 1. to 5. for column 'b' and 'c'.

Are there easy ways to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: There are easy ways to do a lot of things.  Please provide a [mcve] including a simple example of your DataFrame, and a desired output

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of this in terms of "rows" and "columns", an equivalent way is to treat the problem as three separate number lists, splitting each list into 3 groups, and then picking 3 numbers each from each of those 9 groups such that their respective index positions aren't repeated in any of the 3 lists (e.g., if we end up picking the number in the 6th position of the 2nd chunk of list 'a', then we can't pick the number in the 6th position in the 2nd chunk of lists 'b' or 'c').

You can use `numpy.array_split` to split a list up into 3 roughly-equal pieces.  The `random` module gives you a handy `random.sample()` function to then let you pick 3 random numbers from each set, for a total of 9 numbers.  But unfortunately since we need to keep track of which index numbers we've used, we have to factor that in.  Here's one approach:

```
import random
import numpy

def process_list(original_list, exclude_indices):
    # Sort the list
    original_list.sort()

    # Split the list into a list of 3 sublists, each about the same size
    mylist_split = [arr.tolist() for arr in numpy.array_split(original_list, 3)]

    # Go through each sublist, checking the corresponding list of indices in exclude_indices
    number_choices = [ ]
    for i in range(3):
        # Look at each chunk of numbers in mylist_split.  If the length is n, then generate
        # a random list of numbers between 0 and n-1 (inclusive), EXCLUDING any index numbers
        # found in exclude_indices[i].
        possible_positions = [ j for j in range(len(mylist_split[i])) if j not in exclude_indices[i] ]

        # Pick 3 random index numbers of what's available.  Then pick the corresponding
        # numbers in those positions.
        chosen_indices = random.sample(possible_positions, 3)
        for k in chosen_indices:
            number_choices.append(mylist_split[i][k])

        # Update exclude_indices[i] to keep track.
        exclude_indices[i] += chosen_indices

    return number_choices, exclude_indices


# Generate some random lists of numbers to work with
length = 50    
a = [int(100*random.random()) for i in range(length) ]
b = [int(100*random.random()) for i in range(length) ]
c = [int(100*random.random()) for i in range(length) ]

exclude_indices = [ [], [], [] ]
a_choices, exclude_indices = process_list(a, exclude_indices)
b_choices, exclude_indices = process_list(b, exclude_indices)
c_choices, exclude_indices = process_list(c, exclude_indices)

print("a is", a)
print("Chosen numbers: ", a_choices)
print("b is", b)
print("Chosen numbers: ", b_choices)
print("c is", c)
print("Chosen numbers: ", c_choices)
```